# In Twitter, how to filter the results of a list?

Tags: twitter

I have created a list - LL (for linguistics list) - containing 2 members :

- languagelog (http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/)
- languagehat (http://languagehat.comBut i

The list, of course, works fine. But suppose I would like to :

- exclude languagelog's tweets containing "chinese"
- include languagehat's tweets only if they contain "russian"

I know how to do that with one search operator :

```
(from:language log -chinese) OR (from:languagehat russian)
```

but it seems it could be interesting to do that via lists, which would allow longer and more complex searches (it might even become a sort of substitute for yahoo pipes, although a very simple one).

Is it possible to include search operators in lists ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct search query for the separate accounts:

```
(from:languagehat OR from:languagelog) lang:ru -lang:zh
```

If you'd like to do similar with a list:

1. create a Twitter list and add the accounts you need into it.
2. click on your list and copy the list ID from the browser's URL line the list ID.
3. in the query below, replace [list_id] with your copied list ID
   `list:[list_id] lang:ru -lang:zh`
4. paste the query in Twitter's search box

Of course, as you suggested, you can build longer and more complex searches on that list.